# Unit testing NSURLConnectionDelegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ios6, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I want to test a method which makes URL request. When response is received in `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method I save the response. The logic I really want to test is whether response was saved or not.

How to test `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method?

**Method I want to test :**

```
- (void) getProfilePictureURL :(NSString *)fbId
{
    //to get picture URL
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", fbId];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (!connection)
    {
        NSLog(@"error while starting the connection");
    }
} 

// NSURLConnectionDelegate method
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // Save response in user defaults
}
```

Comment: check if the response is saved in userdefault or not?? thats where you can identify that data is saved.

Comment: I know that but I can test it only after connection delegate is called and code is executed. How do I check that delegate is called?

Comment: sorry but i can't understand your scenario. you want to check it before saving response or after saving response ??

Comment: Obviously after saving response. But I have to wait until connection delegate is called. Then only I can test.

Comment: obviously. delegate methods saves the data in userdefault then you need to check it there. otherwise there will be no data before that delegate method is called.

Comment: In unit testing how do I check when delegate method is called?

Comment: have you stored data using any key in userdefaults?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35983/discussion-between-akash-and-armaan-stranger)

Answer (score 0):

The NSURLConnection class does not have any methods of its own to return the http response code so treats a 404 as a successful response - which I suppose it is as a connection was made and something (the 404 page) was returned.

The trick to see if the response was a 200 OK or 404 NOT FOUND is to cast the NSURLResponse to a NSHTTPURLResponse and then use that classes methods to look for the http response code.

Note: If the connection was made the delegate will be called definitely. You should just check if the connection is not made, then what you should be doing.

Comment: I have some code in delegate method and I want to test that code. So I can test only once delegate is called and code is executed.

Comment: So that is the question that how to do it? means HOW TO WAIT for delegate to be called?

Comment: You dont have to wait for it to be called. As soon as you request for a connection it will automatically go in those delegate functions even if there is no internet connection.

Comment: Also make sure you have added `NSURLConnectionDelegate` in your header file.

Comment: It takes a second to call delegate and before that my test method gets executed.

Comment: Is your delegate method getting called.? Did you check.?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35994/discussion-between-akash-and-believe-anky)